# Reading http request using scanner golang

Tags: http, go, request

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    li, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer li.Close()

    for {
        conn, err := li.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err.Error())
            continue
        }
        go handle(conn)
    }

}

func handle(conn net.Conn) {
    defer conn.Close()

    //Read Request
    request(conn)

    //write response
    respond(conn)
}
func request(conn net.Conn) {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(conn)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        ln := scanner.Text()
        fmt.Println(ln)
    }

}

func respond(conn net.Conn) {
    body := `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title></title></head><body><strong>Hello World</strong></body></html>`

    // fmt.Fprintf(conn, "")
    fmt.Fprint(conn, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n")
    fmt.Fprintf(conn, "Content-Length: %d\r\n", len(body))
    fmt.Fprint(conn, "Content-Type: text/html\r\n")
    fmt.Fprint(conn, "\r\n")
    fmt.Fprint(conn, body)
}
```

The scanner reads some data, prints it and then blocks indefinitely and the client never gets back a response. What splitFunc should I implement here so that scanner detects that there is no more data available to be read?

I test it using

curl -X GET "localhost:8080"

output that I see before scanner gets blocked

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*
```

Would greatly appreciate help in understanding this.

Comment: All lines in HTTP 1.x must be terminated by a sequence CR+LF, and in your example you're using a sole LF to terminate the status line. Please see [RFC 7230](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3).

Comment: As to the problem itself, if in your `request` function you want to read a full request, you're supposed to properly _interpret_ it as determining when a particular HTTP request ends heavily depends on the request's _content_—at a minimum you 1) have to parse the `Content-Length` header field and interpret its value as the length of the payload; 2) read past the header; 3) based on whether the request indicated it has a payload of non-zero length, read that payload or take for granted there is none. Note that there exist a way to transfer payloads of unspecified length in HTTP 1.x.

Comment: Another problem with your `request` code is that you never check for an error from the scanner. That's not the reason why the reading code blocks but its something which you must have.

Comment: All-in-all, it looks to me that your code is based on certain assumptions you're maintaining, which are wrong. Since RFC 7230 might be a bit too academic to digest, you could proabably start at MDN or a similar resource. For instance [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages) looks like an okay-quality introduction to HTTP.

Comment: To say more about the particular problem, I suppose `curl` sends its request but does not close its side of the TCP connection afterwards—as is typical for most real-world clients, and especially web browsers (they are not obliged to do that), and waits for response. Since your scanning code does not ever see the curl's (writing) side of the connection closed, it never receives an `io.EOF` "error" and hence never stops its reading loop.

Comment: @kostix would the curl program not take care of sending the carriage return/newline? What code change do you suggest that I should make to handle this correctly?

Comment: `curl` is of course sending CRLFs as it's HTTP-compliant. The problem with CRLF is with your code sending the response. As to the code change—I do not know how to answer that question since I think you would consider "scrap it, read the docs and re-write the solution so that it's HTTP-compliant" to be a glib response. But I do not have another one, sorry: as I've suggested, you're trying to write some code w/o having in your mind a correct idea about how HTTP _protocol_ works. It's impossible to write correctly-behaving code which is based on wrong assumptions.

Comment: To begin with, have you fully understood my comments which mentioned `curl` not closing its side of the connection, `Content-Length` field in the request's header (or its absence) and `io.EOF`? If yes, you should be able to understand what to fix, if not, you should read some docs I pointed you at; there's no other approach we could employ here.